# TFS API - How to fetch work item(s) from specific Team Project

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to query a single team project in the main `TfsTeamProjectCollection` which contains 194 Team Projects in total. I know exactly how to get a `WorkItem` by Id from a `WorkItemStore`. The thing is, that by doing this, the API searches in *ALL* of the projects in the collection and the query takes about a minute. This is way too slow, there must be a way to query work items directly from a single team project ? Here is the code I have:

```
    private Uri collectionUri;
    private TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection;
    private WorkItemStore workItemStore;

    public Project GetTeamProject()
    {
        projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri);

        workItemStore = projectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects[TFS_PROJECT_KEY];
        return teamProject;
    }
```

Now that I have the Team Project I'm interested in, how can I query for work items by ID or just get all work items in this project ?

Comment: FYI, get rid of that try/catch block. It does nothing.

Comment: it used to catch a nullpointerexception because the method would take a project id as a parameter, but I changed it.

Comment: All you did is rethrow the exception, which is the same as not catching it at all. You should also never catch NullReferenceException, as it always means a programming error.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer... But this is a bit out of scope

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's probably most efficient to [use a query to find the workitems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb133074%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you're interested in. You can add a Where project = '@Project' to the query to limit the scope to just that project. By first calling BeginQuery and then EndQuery you'll get a workitem collection for just the items you were looking for.

The easiest way to get the required wql query is to create a query in Team Explorer, then use file->save as (in edit mode) to save it to file. Open that file in Notepad to copy the query out of there.

Alternatively you can use the [WorkItemStore.Query method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore.query%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) directly to achieve the same thing.

Comment: The saving of the wql query is a brilliant tip. Much easier to get your query right using Team Explorer GUI. You've saved me hours of messing about :-)

Answer (score 35):

You could try something like this for getting all WIs within `teamProject`:

```
WorkItemCollection workItemCollection = workItemStore.Query(
     " SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType],"+    
     " [System.State], [System.AssignedTo], [System.Title] "+ 
     " FROM WorkItems " +
     " WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '" + teamProject.Name +
    "' ORDER BY [System.WorkItemType], [System.Id]");
```

And this to get a specific WorkItem ID:

```
WorkItem workItem = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(555);
```

Comment: Do you know what reference to add to the project for the query to be recognized? Because I already am using `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` and `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client` and I get errors for everything in parameter of `workItemStore.Query()`

Comment: Note that, just as with SQL Queries, you can use @ParameterName to add parameters to your Team queries. Just add a Dictionary as last parameter with the name/value pairs and the WorkItemStore will make sure the data is properly escaped. (see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb140400(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I am just throwing it out there, if you want a specific work item you have to filter for it like so: " AND [System.Id] = " + workItemID; - that wasn't explicitly stated above, no biggy.