# Show TFS Tasks in my application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, task

I use `Team foundation 2012` and my application developed by `C#`. Can I show all tasks in `TFS` that closed with priority 1 in my application.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [Query class, specifically its constructor.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb133074%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Or [WorkItemStore.Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb140399%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Here is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130319%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to do it. It basically accepts a query string that you use when querying the TFS using the client.

Btw, this is somewhat related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266437/tfs-api-how-to-fetch-work-items-from-specific-team-project). Yours is for a specific query.